# How to send/receive data to another device with Mono for Android using WiFi?

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.android

I am new to Mono.
But I want to know is that possible to send and receive a string or some other data to another device (specific IP address) with **Mono For Android**? If yes How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

As described in mono [api](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aJava.Net.ServerSocket) you can use binding on standard java ServerSocket and ClientSocket classes. Example of such usage you can find [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/). I think there is no problem in mapping java to C# code.